# Hyperledger-fabric2.0 run first-network failure. failed to read chaincode package at '.tar.gz'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

## environment

CentOS7， 
go version go1.13.8 linux/amd64
Docker version 19.03.6

Hyperledger-fabric 2.0

## My steps

1.download fabric-samples 
2.run `byfn.sh generate` in `/fabric-sample/first-network/` this step is ok 
3.run `byfn.sh up` then i got failure

## Failure

===================== Chaincode is packaged on peer0.org1 =====================

Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install .tar.gz
+ res=1
+ set +x
Error: failed to read chaincode package at '.tar.gz': open .tar.gz: no such file or directory
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

## I tried

### 1.

i tried use  `peer lifecycle chaincode` to tar chaincode , that network should be run, and docker container should be there .. so i can't use peer lifecycle to tar

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same issue too! This appears to be an issue in Hyperledger 1.4.5, to fix downgrade to v1.4.4

Here's how I solved it.

1. In your first-network directory shut down the ledger

   `./byfn.sh down`
2. Remove the fabric-samples directory

   `rm -r <download location>/fabric-samples`
3. Install version 1.4.4: curl -sSL

   `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 1.4.6 1.4.6 0.4.18`
4. export the /bin to your PATH

   `export PATH=<path to download location>/bin:$PATH`
5. `cd fabric-samples/first-networks`
6. `./byfn.sh generate`
7. either `./byfn.sh up`,  `./byfn.sh up -l node`, or what I used `./byfn.sh up -l java`

Answer (score 0):

The issue what I see here is your chaincode package file (tar.gz) is not found.That means the chaincode package command is failing everytime.

Have you checked inside the docker "chaincodename.tar.gz" is built every-time you run the script.If not then,

First check the tools are available in the "bin" folder and path is exported as well.
You can try packaging and installing the chaincode steps manually to know more in detail what is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not you, there was a regression in the fabric-samples code, if
   you want to keep going right now you can do a git reset --hard
   e204ebb3b2749b72621fa05fc753f4bea1ff7976 to drop the bad change
2. Long story short, a chaincode label variable was added, but not
   passed around accordingly to the correct functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, they seems to fix the problem. You need to do a `git pull` on root directory of `fabric-sample`.

My current commit number is `e5b898c08d86e35bd80db8024a0c3eed6a9abcb2` and I am using `master` branch.